# How to mount a pen drive in Red Hat inside VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am running VirtualBox on a Windows XP host. Red Hat Linux 5.2 GUI is running inside VirtualBox. I want to use my USB pen drive inside Red Hat - it is visible from Windows XP but not from Red Hat.

Can anyone tell me what might be the problem and how I should fix it? I am new to using Linux.

Comment: Can anybody tell me what is the problem in question. Actually I want to install oracle 11g on linux which setup is in pendrive but unable to mount the pendrive in linux redhat, so please clearly tell me is there any problem in my question

Comment: there is not problem in your question i think, why do you think there is a problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Install the [VirtualBox extension pack](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Once installed, you will have to attach it from Devices -> USB devices menu

[image: VirtualBox]